# How to redirect users to a custom form using short URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, url-rewriting, short-url

I have a project where users would navigate to a provided shortURL, which would redirect everyone to a similar looking form with different business names.

Currently I have a **MySQL** database that looks as follows:

```
tbl_Codes
- shortURL (string of 5 alphanumeric characters)
- businessID (ID of business which matches the ID in the table below)

tbl_Business
- businessID
- businessName
- other fields....
```

So someone who navigates to *example.com/12345* sees a form with the name of the business which matches the businessID, and someone who navigates to *example.com/abcde* sees a the same form but with the name of a different business.

Would [something like this](http://www.sean-o.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/11/tutorial-how-to-create-your-own-url-shortener/) be the best way to do it? If not, how?

The linked script uses **PHP regex** to get the shortURL, match the string in the database then perform a **301 redirect**. If not matched, it redirects to the 404 page (though I probably wouldn't do the 404 bit).

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code in case you don't want to click the link. It's from a tutorial:

```
<?php
$expectedURL = trim($_SERVER['URL']);
$split = preg_split("{:80\/}",$expectedURL);
$shortURL = $split[1];
// security: strip all but alphanumerics & dashes
$shortURL = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]+/i", "", $shortURL);

// Check this string to see if it matches a short URL in our database.

$isShortURL = false;
$result = getLongURL($shortURL);
if ($result) { $isShortURL = true; }
$longURL = $result['longURL'];

// Finally, we check to see if our $isShortURL flag is set.
// If a matching short URL was found, we’ll redirect to it.
// If not, we’ll display our standard 404.

if ($isShortURL)
{
    redirectTo($longURL, $shortURL);
} else {
    show404();  // no shortURL found, display standard 404 page
}

//The primary function:
// Get the long URL associated with the passed short URL, if it exists.

function getLongURL($s)
{
    // define these variables for your system
    $host = ""; $user = ""; $pass = ""; $db = "";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    // you may just want to fall thru to 404 here if connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { die("Unable to connect !"); }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE shorturl = '$s';";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            return($row);
        }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}

//Perform the URL redirection.

function redirectTo($longURL)
{
    // change this to your domain
    header("Referer: http://www.your-domain-here.com");
    // use a 301 redirect to your destination
    header("Location: $longURL", TRUE, 301);
    exit;
}

//Finally, display your standard 404 page here.

function show404()
{
    // display/include your standard 404 page here
    echo "404 Page Not Found.";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: wouldent it not be easier to have a form.php page and set a GET var in the top when you click externaly the url link? so for example you go from page index.php > form.php?busName=someBussiness, on that page use $_GET["busName"];?

Comment: I don't think so. Users are not coming from the site, so should be redirected straight to the pre-filled form using the short URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link you posted is.... alright.... ish. There are better ways to do that though. However, in your case, I don't think this is what you need?

Without looking at your code in-depth, don't use regex. Use your htaccess file and do a mod_rewrite to pass the "short url" in as a query parameter. Access this via the PHP script using the $_GET super global. It doesn't look like you even need to do a redirect at all? Just pull the necessary data out using the business id.

Additionally, before you go any further, start using PDO if possible, and build a DB class (wrapper) for it. A more OOP approach will serve you better in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not much of a back-end developer so I learn as I go. I'm only vaguely familiar with .htaccess from GZipping files and removing the 'www'. Do you have an example of how this might be done? Sadly, PDOs and DB classes are a bit above my level at the moment.

Comment: No probs, this should be helpful: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: Reading around, this does seem like a very good option. I'm still not there yet, but this is certainly a good response.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, does your suggestion work like this? mod_rewrite takes the "short url" and write it as `example.com/form.php?businessID=12345` - at which point I use $_get to lookup the database with the `12345`?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. What's brilliant is that mod_rewrite doesn't just do a redirect, your url will still look "pretty" and the fact that the businessID is being passed through to the form.php script as a query string will be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm posting this much too often: The line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE shorturl = '$s';";
```

Looks like the perfect [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) candidate to me

[image]

(Also known as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Comment: Appreciate the intention, but the code sample was from a tutorial. I don't think it would be used verbatim on a production site.

Comment: @Joe, trust me it is lots of times.